# Running Scheduled Task - .sh file not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, schedule

I'm trying to run an sh file to move files around with scheduled tasks.  See GUI pic.  The result from "run Selected Task" is:

```
/tmp/tmp8yj5zs: line 1: /home/dan/Foscam/move-video.sh: Permission denied
Press ENTER to continue and close this window.
```

If I add sudo to the front I get:

```
 sudo: /home/dan/Foscam/move-video.sh: command not found
Press ENTER to continue and close this window.
```

The Sh file is

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/find /home/foscam/FI9803P_C4D655404959/record/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_2/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_2/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_3/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_3/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_4/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_4/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

It does not seem like images is working for me so the command is `home/dan/Foscam/move-video.sh`run as Xapplication

`#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file seems to do the same.

Comment: running your script directly `/home/dan/Foscam/move-video.sh` is working? did you try adding `bash` to `bash /home/dan/Foscam/move-video.sh` in TASK command section? does the script is executable?

Comment: It was executable but when I checked it was not so must have gotten changed during an edit.  It now runs.  It is nto doing what I wnat but at least now I can try and debug.

Comment: Yes, also note that with your script you are just deleting everything in this path `/home/foscam/FI9803P_C4D655404959/record/` in result!! be aware of this

Comment: Probably you want it the other way round, first delete week4 dir, then move 3 to 4, move 2 to 3, move current to 2. Looks like a job for logrotate :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but I did get it to work.  At this point I don't quite remember how.  I think I had issues with the file changing to a non executable. See below

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/find /home/foscam/FI9803P_C4D655404959/record/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_2/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_2/ -type f -mtime +6 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_3/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_3/ -type f -mtime +9 -exec mv '{}' /home/dan/Foscam/Week_4/ \;
/usr/bin/find /home/dan/Foscam/Week_4/ -type f -mtime +13 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

[image]